# ipython - docstring not showing for functions that are wrapped

Tags: python, ipython

With the code below entered in ipython, entering subsequent `func_with_wrap?` shows `<no docstring>` while `func_no_wrap?` shows the docstring as expected. How can I get `func_with_wrap?` to properly show the docstring of `func_with_wrap`?

```py
def wrap(f):
    """
    wrap docstring
    """
    def wrapped():
        return
    return wrapped

@wrap
def func_with_wrap():
    """
    func_with_wrap docstring
    """
    return

def func_no_wrap():
    """
    func_no_wrap docstring
    """
    return
```

Here are the outputs:

```
In [12]: func_with_wrap?
Signature: func_with_wrap()
Docstring: <no docstring>
File:      c:\confidential>
Type:      function

In [13]: func_no_wrap?
Signature: func_no_wrap()
Docstring: func_no_wrap docstring
File:      c:\confidential>
Type:      function
```

EDIT:

When tryin the following:

```
def wrap(f):
    """
    wrap docstring
    """
    def wrapped():
        wrapped.__doc__ = f.__doc__
        return
    return wrapped
```

`ipython` still does not show `func_with_wrap`'s docstring.

BUT,

```
def wrap(f):
    """
    wrap docstring
    """
    def wrapped():
        return
    wrapped.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return wrapped
```

does work.

Comment: Which doctoring would you like to see? The one from the wrapper or the one from the wrapped function?

Comment: It's `wrapped`, not `wrap`, that needs a docstring. `wrapped` is what gets assigned to `func_with_wrap`.

Comment: @AxelDonath I would like to see the docstring from the function that was wrapped (func_with_wrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function `def wrapped():` (declared inside `wrap`) has no docstring, no docstring is present for `func_with_wrap`. Decorators work on functions by replacing them with the return value of the decorator passed the decorated function. It's mostly equivalent to the following named lambda behavior:

```py
func_with_wrap = lambda: <code that was in 'def func_with_wrap' block>
func_with_wrap = wrap(func_with_wrap)
```

While you *could* add a docstring to the inner `def wrapped` call in your example, that would be a bit unusual. Since most decorators are (as your symbol names suggest) wrappers that augment the decorated function rather than completely replacing it with something else, it's considered a best practice to propagate attributes (like the docstring, function name, and type annotations) from the function being wrapped--`func_with_wrap` in your example--to the return value of the decorator--`wrapped` in your example.

Most people do this using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), like so:

```py
from functools import wraps

def wrap(f):
    """
    wrap docstring
    """
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped():
        ...
    return wrapped
```

You can also do this by hand, by manually assigning `__doc__` from the decorated function to the return value of the decorator, like this:

```py
def wrap(f):
    """
    wrap docstring
    """

    def wrapped():
        ...
    wrapped.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return wrapped
```

Comment: The functools.wraps is definitely the preferred route as it fixes not only the docstring, but the source code with `func_with_wrap??`

Comment: It doesn't do anything to the source code, but it does propagate other attributes besides the docstring: specifically, the function's module location, name, and type annotations.